# Deactivate the standby mode in the smartwatch

Tags: sony, standby, sony-smartwatch

I've a control application for the smartwatch and the device goes automatically to standby mode. Is there any way to deactivate the standby mode?, I need to show the info displayed the whole time. I know that this will reduce the battery life (perhaps dramatically), but it is indispensable on my application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily control the screen state of the SmartWatch by sending the CONTROL_SET_SCREEN_STATE_INTENT intent to the SmartWatch host application, which will then propagate the state to the SmartWatch device. The available states are:

- SCREEN_STATE_OFF
- SCREEN_STATE_DIM
- SCREEN_STATE_ON
- SCREEN_STATE_AUTO

If you are using the [SmartExtension SDK](http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/tool-guides/download-the-new-smart-extension-sdk-and-create-smart-extras-apps/), which I suggest you do, you can make use of the ControlExtension utility class which provides the method `setScreenState(int state)`. There is extensive documentation available in the SDK - read more about changing screen state in the "SmartExtention API Specification", chapter 6.2.

Good luck!

Comment: How can you wake it up from a dimmed state? Similar like touching the screen on the SmartWatch but in code?