# disable standby mode smarteyeglass

Tags: sony-smarteyeglass

My problem is that the SmartEyeglass display is disabled after around 30 seconds of non-activity.

The SmartEyeglassUtils lib provides a `requestEnterStandbyMode()` method. But not a disableStandbyMode or something like that.

How can I disable the standby mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable standby mode completely using following method call provided in SmartExtension API:

```
setScreenState(Control.Intents.SCREEN_STATE_ON);
```

Later when your app is closed, you can switch it back to automatic mode to avoid causing battery drain on SmartEyeglass.

```
 setScreenState(Control.Intents.SCREEN_STATE_AUTO);
```

You can see a similar question here. It is applicable for Sony SmartWatch 2 as well, because both devices are using SmartExtension API:
[Tap on SmartWatch screen in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543624/tap-on-smartwatch-screen-in-code)